# ROS 2 - where to find updated guides on driver implementation in ROS2

Tags: ros2, driver, hardware

On the official ROS 1 website I can find a series of tutorial on "How to write a driver", but I can't find anything regarding drivers in ROS 2.

Where can I find updated resources? Tutorial, guides, courses. Anything goes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're talking about: http://wiki.ros.org/Drivers/Tutorials

In general there's a lot of content in ROS 1 that has been generated. The concepts are generally the same. You will need to make adjustments to use [`rclcpp`](https://index.ros.org/p/rclcpp/) instead of [`roscpp`](https://index.ros.org/p/roscpp/#noetic) or [`rclpy`](https://index.ros.org/p/rclpy/) instead of [`rospy`](https://index.ros.org/p/rospy/#noetic)

There's a general guides to Migrating from ROS 1 to ROS 2 here: https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Migrating-from-ROS1.html?highlight=migrating

You can use these guides to leverage any of the large set of ROS 1 documentation in ROS 2. And if there's content that you find useful enough to port yourself please consider contributing it to the repository or project where it's most closely associated.

Comment: Thanks Tully! I'll give it a try!